# Setting the initial point of a line

Tags: r, point, line

I've been working on a project that consists in plotting points, which are not georeferenced, by their odometric position on a line, which is georeferenced. Eg.: Point 1 is 325 meter away from the starting point of the line.

Well, I managed to do that. But, I couldn't define what point of the line is the starting point. By default, it took the southernmost(?) point.

To invert, because my starting point actually was the other extreme, I simply did `('line length' - 'odometric position')`, which worked just fine.

But is there any way to set the initial point of a vector?

[image]

Below are some URLs of me trying to solve the problems I described first.

Coordinates by odometer distance:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75995704/coordinates-by-odometer-distance/75996465#75996465

Defining start point from a SpatialLineDataFrame:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76008830/defining-start-point-from-a-spatiallinedataframe?noredirect=1#comment134056623_76008830

Comment: Please decide which software you're working with.

Comment: well, I work with all of them. It depends on I need. I prefer using R, but I know R isn't the best to work with spacial data. Have been said that, when I need some more complex features I go with arcgis pro or qgis.

Comment: That's not how we work. We use a Focused question/Best answer model. Choose a task and make an attempt with a specific platform to resolve the task, then document what you attempted and what went wrong.

Comment: hmm, got it. Sorry, I'm not used to this platform yet. More used to stackoverflow... I'll edit the question and select the platform as you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy in the sf package, which has a function st_reverse

```
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

# make a simple line feature that goes from 0,0 to 1,1
path<-st_linestring(x = matrix(c(0,1,0,1),nrow = 2), dim = "XY")
# Reverse the geometry
path<-st_reverse(path)

# Set the desired distance along the path
desired_distance <- 1
ratio <- desired_distance / st_length(path)
# find the coordinates of the point
pt2 <- st_linesubstring(path, from = 0, to = ratio) %>%st_endpoint()
```

I borrowed code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987924/find-coordinates-x-distance-along-linestring